# Is X-24 a cyborg or bionic?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, wolverine, marvel, logan

In the movie *Logan*, a character gets introduced called **[X-24](http://xmenmovies.wikia.com/wiki/X-24)**, a mutant weapon created by Transigen, who is actually

> a juiced-up fresh clone of Logan himself.

What I'm interested to know is, **is X-24 a cyborg or bionic?** <sup>excluding his "skeleton"</sup>

I ask this because there was a scene where X-24 attacks the Munson's house, and Dr. Rice and Donald Pierce were watching X-24's viewpoint from the surveillance van. But I can't see anything about being a cyborg and there's no shared/camera vision listed in his [abilities page.](http://xmenmovies.wikia.com/wiki/X-24#Powers.2C_Abilities.2C_.26_Weaknesses)

Comment: What definition of cyborg are you using?

Comment: @CreationEdge My understanding of a Cyborg is a mixed human/robot creature. Also, the main thing I'm interested in is how Dr. Rice and Pierce were able to see what X-24 was seeing, in what seemed to me a POV feed.

Comment: So, whether or not there are more cybernetics to him than just [contact lenses with cameras](http://mashable.com/2016/04/05/samsung-smart-contact-lenses-patent/#kZLUb1lb9aqU)?

Comment: There were a couple comments in the movie that made me wonder this, too. Like, "making something without a soul" and "he only listens to you" which made him seem more robotic, yet he seemed to be *grown*. And he's clearly meant to be an allusion to [Albert](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Albert_(Earth-616)) (clicking might be a spoiler, beware!), but didn't seem terribly robotic. I'm hoping there's some director's commentary out there.

Comment: @Creation Agreed, there isn't much to go on, except the whole POV stuff. I don't personally think he was cybernetic/bionic, I just need facts :)

Comment: He was grown in a lab from start to finish. If any implants were placed within him during / after this process, it isn't stated in the movie. Therefore, we don't have enough evidence to say one way or another. In short, we don't know.

Answer (score 3):

### No, X-24 is *not* bionic in any way (except for his Adamantium skeleton)

I have just re-read the official screenplay for the movie and can confirm that X-24 is just a clone of The Wolverine (Logan). The writers mention that 'Bad Logan' is a copy of Logan, and later point out that it's a bodycam that we see the feed through.

Here are the relevant parts:

> Charles LOOKS UP FROM HIS WOUND, blood coming. He tries to
> reach a bedside light and succeeds as again-- THE CLAWS
> PLUNGE INTO HIS CHEST. IN THE LIGHT WE SEE -- THIS IS A
> PERFECT DOUBLE OF LOGAN.
>
> For simplicity’s sake, let’s call this creature BAD LOGAN.
> He will also be referenced as “X-24”, his model number. He
> is a younger, stronger, clone of The Wolverine. Feral, he
> moves in a slight crouch. He is not the absence of emotion
> but rather, the presence of it, most noticeably, rage.
>
> <sup>*-Logan, Screenplay (Final Shooting Draft), Frank, S., Mangold, J., and Green, M., 2019.*</sup>

and later:

> A METALLIC THWACK as the bat connects with Bad Logan’s head,
> but the clone hardly registers the impact AS WE CUT TO :
>
> **INT. ALKALI COMMAND VEHICLE -- COUNTRY ROAD -- CONTINUOUS**
>
> The tinny transmitted sounds of the violence play off screen
> as we look at the Munson farmhouse a ways off through a
> windshield. PAN TO REVEAL--
>
> WE'RE IN THE ALKALI COMMAND VEHICLE. PIERCE AND DR. RICE are
> riveted to **a feed from Bad Logan’s bodycam**.
>
> <sup>*Ibid.*</sup>

[image]

[image]

In the final movie it's a little bit difficult to see any bodycam present, which is why it confused me originally:

Comment: Not directly relevant to the question, but X-24 is also notable because, in scenes where he and Logan are present, he's apparently entirely digital, which I certainly did not notice.